# Schema created but tables therein cannot be displayed

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Here is the code:

```
testdb=# create schema myschema1;
CREATE SCHEMA
testdb=# \d
          List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  | Owner
--------+------------+-------+--------
 public | company    | table | kaiyin
 public | department | table | kaiyin
(2 rows)

testdb=#
testdb=# create table myschema1.company1(
testdb(#    ID   INT              NOT NULL,
testdb(#    NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
testdb(#    AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
testdb(#    ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
testdb(#    SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
testdb(#    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
testdb(#    );
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# \d
          List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  | Owner
--------+------------+-------+--------
 public | company    | table | kaiyin
 public | department | table | kaiyin
(2 rows)

testdb=# select * from myschema1.company1
```

Nothing appears. Maybe it's because the table is empty?

```
testdb=# insert into myschema1.company1 values (1, joyce, 23, amsterdam, 60000, 1)
testdb-# select * from myschema1.company1
testdb-#
```

Still nothing. Why?

OS X, postgresql 9.4.4

Answer (score 3):

The `\d` command in psql uses the current search list of schemas, which by default is `public`.  You need to tell it to search your schema:  `\d myschema1.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate a statement with a `;`

As written you are actually writing a multi-line statement.  That's why your prompt turned from `testdb=#` to `testdb-#`, it means you're still writing your statement.  *(It usefully does the same with braces too, and gives a prompt of `testdb(#` if you're still within a braced-block.)*

Press `<ctrl>-<c>` to cancel your current statement, then try it as follows.

```
insert into myschema1.company1 values (1, joyce, 23, amsterdam, 60000, 1);
select * from myschema1.company1;
```